# How to check XML file if node exists and retrieve value in Progress4GL

Tags: xml, openedge, progress-4gl

Hello Progress4GL Developers,

I have the following XML response stored in a longchar variable called cBody after making a successful SOAP call to UPS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<trk:TrackResponse xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:trk="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Track/v2.0">
  <common:Response xmlns:common="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0">
    <common:ResponseStatus>
      <common:Code>1</common:Code>
      <common:Description>Success</common:Description>
    </common:ResponseStatus>
    <common:TransactionReference/>
  </common:Response>
  <trk:Shipment>
    <trk:InquiryNumber>
      <trk:Code>01</trk:Code>
      <trk:Description>ShipmentIdentificationNumber</trk:Description> 
      <trk:Value>MYTRACKERNUMBER</trk:Value>
    </trk:InquiryNumber>
 ...
```

I now store this as as a X-DOCUMENT using the following line of code:

```
hDoc:LOAD("longchar",cBody2,FALSE).
```

Now I would like to check if my response has a tracking number, and if it does I would like to store the tracking number as a variable. It appears that this is possible: 
https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvxml/examples-of-reading-an-input-xml-file.html

However this is what I have so far, and it doesn't seem to work. Nothing is outputted but no runtime errors:

```
....
hDoc:LOAD("longchar",cBody,FALSE).

DEFINE variable hNodeRef as HANDLE NO-UNDO.
CREATE X-NODEREF hNodeRef.

hDoc:GET-DOCUMENT-ELEMENT(hNodeRef).
IF hNodeRef:NAME = "trk:value" THEN
message hNoderef:GET-ATTRIBUTE("id") hNoderef:ATTRIBUTE-NAMES.
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Peter's answer is not wrong, it can be a lot simpler to use the power of automatic XML to DataSet mapping. In this case you do not even need to model the dataset statically to the XML, the ABL will do it automatically for you:

```
def var lcresponse as longchar initial '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<trk:TrackResponse xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:trk="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Track/v2.0">
  <common:Response xmlns:common="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0">
    <common:ResponseStatus>
      <common:Code>1</common:Code>
      <common:Description>Success</common:Description>
    </common:ResponseStatus>
    <common:TransactionReference/>
  </common:Response>
  <trk:Shipment>
    <trk:InquiryNumber>
      <trk:Code>01</trk:Code>
      <trk:Description>ShipmentIdentificationNumber</trk:Description> 
      <trk:Value>MYTRACKERNUMBER</trk:Value>
    </trk:InquiryNumber>
  </trk:Shipment>
</trk:TrackResponse>'.

def var hds as handle no-undo.
def var hb  as handle no-undo.

create dataset hds.
hds:read-xml( "longchar", lcresponse, ?, ?, ? ).
hb = hds:get-buffer-handle("InquiryNumber").
hb:find-unique() no-error.
if hb:available then 
   message hb:buffer-field("Value"):buffer-value.
```

https://abldojo.services.progress.com:443/#/?shareId=5ed946344b1a0f40c34b8c5a

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I was wondering how this was possible because the data is in a node called 'value' which is a keyword to be a static temp-table field, but this is the solution and working brilliantly! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, reserved keywords can be a nuisance, in this case it prevented the :: shortcut form (message hb::Value). For static temp-tables you can usually get around this by using serialize-name (so: field myvalue serialize-name "value").

Answer (score 2):

You need to walk down the tree to get to the node you want. Something like the below works. It's labourious, and you will need to clean up after yourself (as in the finally block).

```
define variable hXmlDoc as handle no-undo.
define variable hXmlNode as handle no-undo.
define variable hXmlNode2 as handle no-undo.
define variable hXmlNode3 as handle no-undo.
define variable loop as integer no-undo.
define variable cnt as integer no-undo.

create x-document hXmlDoc.
hXmlDoc:load('file', 'soap.xml', no).

create x-noderef hXmlNode.
create x-noderef hXmlNode2.
create x-noderef hXmlNode3.

hXmlDoc:get-document-element(hXmlNode).

cnt = hXmlNode:num-children.
do loop = 1 to cnt:
    hXmlNode:get-child(hXmlNode2, loop).
    if hXmlNode2:name eq 'trk:Shipment' then
        leave.
end.     

cnt = hXmlNode2:num-children.
do loop = 1 to cnt:
    hXmlNode2:get-child(hXmlNode3, loop).
    if hXmlNode3:name eq 'trk:InquiryNumber' then
        leave.
end.

// should be trk:InquiryNumber
cnt = hXmlNode3:num-children.
do loop = 1 to cnt:
    hXmlNode3:get-child(hXmlNode, loop).
    if hXmlNode:name eq 'trk:Value' then
        leave.
end.

// should be trk:Value
hXmlNode:get-child(hXmlNode2, 1).

message 
hXmlNode:name skip
hXmlNode2:node-value
view-as alert-box.
finally:
    delete object hXmlNode.
    delete object hXmlNode2.
    delete object hXmlNode3.
    delete object hXmlDoc.    
end finally.
```

Comment: Thanks @nwahmaet, This is very helpful to understand how to use the x-noderef handles to get to what I need in an XML file. :)